# What does this Linux command do?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, rhel5, rpm

I have by a mistake written this command on a CentOS server

```
xargs rpm -e|rpm -qa|grep test11
```

where I meant

```
rpm -qa|grep test11|xargs rpm -e
```

which should uninstall all packages matching "test11".

Can someone figure out what the first command do? I am afraid that it un-install ALL packages =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No worries, it just executed 'rpm -e' which would not remove any package.

```
[root@web420 ~]# rpm -e
rpm: no packages given for erase
```

BTW, for verifying you have not removed all packages you could just run

```
rpm -qa
```

and see the list of installed packages.

Comment: As long as you specified no input to xargs "rpm -e" should bail out with an error message and the rest of the chain "does nothing" (at least in terms of modification)

Comment: For the future, specify `--test` to potentially-destructive RPM commands (like `-e`): It will tell you what it's going to do without actually changing your system so you can avoid unplesant surprises.

Comment: @voretaq7 great point!

Comment: @voretaq7: Excellent trick. I will clearly use that from now on =)

Comment: By the way: if you removed all packages from RHEL, it wouldn't run at all! Everything is a package, right down to the filesystem layout.

Answer (score 0):

The first command you gave will not remove all packages (phew!). Here is the command you gave:

```
xargs rpm -e|rpm -qa|grep test11
```

The command *rpm -e* does remove RPMs, but with xargs listed without a pipe, it takes its input from the terminal and waits for your input. The second command would essentially replace the output from *rpm -e* with *rpm -qa* (all RPMs) then find the RPM test11 (if it exists).

Not a command string worth running, but certainly one worth understanding...